# Which term is correct Datafication or Datification?

Tags: terminology

I have recently started reading [Introduction to Data Science: A python approach to Concepts, Techniques, and Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-50017-1#authorsandaffiliationsbook)  and taking notes on Data Science.

Chapter 1 repeatedly uses the term Datification(the process of rendering into data aspects of the world that have never been quantified before). I could not find the word in the dictionary and the web shows some results but with different spellings Datafication(a technological trend turning many aspects of our life into data).

I am wondering which one is correct?

Comment: This is a contrived term that is likely unique only to this author's text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a neologism, there's no standard spelling or even meaning.

For the record there are related terms which are more standard: "data representation" (usually low-level) or "[knowledge representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_representation_and_reasoning)".